How to create fixed rulers, but scrollable together with the content
In the application, I have to display a document and there are two rulers assigned to the browsing to help which row and column we are looking at. The document may be large, so it should be scrollable, but the rulers should always be visible. Here is the problem, if I set the rulers to a fixed position then when we scroll the content, then rulers don't scroll together with the document and then they show the wrong row and column values. What should I do to ensure that the rulers are always visible and follow the scrolled document?



body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 90vh;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 16px;
  padding: 16px;
}

.rulerVertical {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 64px;
  width: 70px;
  min-width: 70px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 90%;
}

.contentAndRulerHorizontal {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.rulerHorizontal {
  display: flex;
  width: 90%;
  height: 70px;
  min-height: 70px;
  background-color: white;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 64px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  overflow: auto;
  
  div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 64px;
    
    div {
      height: 17.78px;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
  }
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="rulerVertical">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
    <span>5</span>
    <span>6</span>
    <span>7</span>
    <span>8</span>
    <span>9</span>
    <span>10</span>
    <span>11</span>
    <span>12</span>
    <span>13</span>
    <span>14</span>
    <span>15</span>
  </div>
  <div class="contentAndRulerHorizontal">
    <div class="rulerHorizontal">
      <span>1</span>
      <span>2</span>
      <span>3</span>
      <span>4</span>
      <span>5</span>
      <span>6</span>
      <span>7</span>
      <span>8</span>
      <span>9</span>
      <span>10</span>
      <span>11</span>
      <span>12</span>
      <span>13</span>
      <span>14</span>
      <span>15</span>
      <span>16</span>
      <span>17</span>
      <span>18</span>
      <span>19</span>
      <span>20</span>
      <span>21</span>
      <span>22</span>
      <span>23</span>
      <span>24</span>
      <span>25</span>
      <span>26</span>
      <span>27</span>
      <span>28</span>
      <span>29</span>
      <span>30</span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div>
        <div>Line 1 Clmn2,,,,,,Clmn 3,,,,,,Clmn4,,,,,,Clmn5,,,,,,Clmn6,,,,,,Clmn7,,,,,,Clmn8,,,,,,Clmn9,,,,,,Clmn10,,,,,,Clmn11,,,,,,Clmn12,,,,,,Clmn13,,,,,,Clmn14,,,,,,Clmn15,,,,,,Clmn16,,,,,,Clmn17,,,,,,Clmn18,,,,,,Clmn19,,,,,,Clmn20,,,,,,Clmn21,,,,,,Clmn22,,,,,,Clmn23,,,,,,Clmn24,,,,,,Clmn25,,,,,,Clmn26,,,,,,Clmn27,,,,,,Clmn28,,,,,,Clmn29,,,,,,Clmn30</div>
        <div>Line 2</div>
        <div>Line 3</div>
        <div>Line 4</div>
        <div>Line 5</div>
        <div>Line 6</div>
        <div>Line 7</div>
        <div>Line 8</div>
        <div>Line 9</div>
        <div>Line 10</div>
        <div>Line 11</div>
        <div>Line 12</div>
        <div>Line 13</div>
        <div>Line 14</div>
        <div>Line 15</div>
        <div>Line 16</div>
        <div>Line 17</div>
        <div>Line 18</div>
        <div>Line 19</div>
        <div>Line 20</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




This question is similar to: HTML table with fixed headers and a fixed column?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
